# Cargar templates y controladores de angular usando require.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo un problema al usar ***require.js*** y ***angular.js*** para cargar módulos de manera asíncrona, y es que muchas veces al hacer un mínimo cambio siempre me aparece el error siguiente:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

**main.js**

Configuración de los archivos javascript en el main de require.js

```
require.config({    
    baseUrl: 'js',    

    paths : {      
        angular: 'libs/angular',
        ngRoute: 'libs/angular-route',
        ngResource: 'libs/angular-resource',
        uiRouter: 'libs/angular-ui-router',
        index: 'app/index'      
    },

    shim: {        
        angular: {
            exports : 'angular'
        }
    }


});

require(['index'], function (index){

});
```

**index.js**

```
define(['angular', 'uiRouter'], function (){


angular.module('AppUPC', ['ui-router'])
        .controller('formulario', formulario)
        .service('obtenerDatos', obtenerDatos)
        .config('rutas', rutas);

formulario.$inject = ['$scope', 'obtenerDatos'];

function formulario($scope, obtenerDatos){

    $scope.login = function(){

        var datos;

        datos = {

            Usuario: $scope.usuariotxt,
            Password: $scope.passwordtxt

        };

        obtenerDatos.Authentication(datos).then(function (response){

            if(response.data){
                console.log(response.data);
            }else{
                console.log(response.status);
            };

        });

     };         

};


obtenerDatos.$inject = ['$http', '$httpParamSerializer'];

function obtenerDatos($http, $httpParamSerializer){

    function Authentication(datos){

        var url = 'http://190.109.185.138/Apipedro/api/login';

        return $http.post(url, $httpParamSerializer(datos), {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }

        });

    };

    return {
        Authentication: Authentication

    };

};

rutas.inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];

function rutas($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");

     $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
            controller: "formulario"
        });

};


});
```

[image: Estructura del proyecto]

[image: Corriendo proyecto]

Comment: llevo dias buscado un hueco para dejarte un comentario sobre lo siguiente pero no encontraba el lugar oportuno. Veo que estas haciendo muchas preguntas sobre Angularjs y puedo ver en la captura que pone practicas, se que este comentario es oftopic, pero prodrias aprender Angular2 si no es que quieres aprender Angularjs para un proyecto inmediato (Aunque ahora mismo Angular2 tiene los conceptos muy firmes a nivel del nucleo), pues puedes leer que Angular2 no sera compatible hacia atras con Angularjs

Comment: (aunque hay formas de usar los dos) creo que seria mas comodo aprender Angular2 en tu situacion, porque despues no tienes que volver a aprender como hacer las cosas de diferente manera con Angular2, puedes leer por la www sobre estos temas pero ten en cuenta, que algunas de las publicaciones son del año pasado, cuando dicen que esta en pañales ect, y no es recomendable para tal o cual cosa. Conclusion puedes tomarte no se una hora en leer esto

Comment: https://angular.io/ e investigar sobre todo el ejemplo y ver si es factible que cambies a Angular2, en ningun momento digo que Angularjs no valga, si no que creo que es mas acertado poner esfuerzo en aprender Angular2 que no Angularjs, espero se entienda lo que te quiero trasmitir Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel Entiendo los motivos de tu comentario, solo quiero hacer una observación, Angular2 es superior a su versión 1 pero es un gran problema cuando estás tratando de hacer un proyecto real que depende de plugins algunos de los cuales no soportan todavía Angular2 como por ejemplo [angular-formly](https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly) lo cual a veces ha sido una barrera de entrada para mis proyectos. Algo parecido sucede con Python y sus versiones 2 y 3. Puede transcurrir algun tiempo para que tenga soporte total así que el aprendizaje de Angular1 no es una mala idea para el autor.

Comment: @devconcept entiendo su punto de vista el cual es totalmente valido, por eso intente hacer el comentario de manera que no pareciera que aprender Angularjs fuera una perdida de tiempo(pues casi siempre lo que aprendes te puede ayudar de una manera u otra), solo le deje alguna cosas sobre las que mirar para que el determinara si era factible o no aprender Angular 2 o Angularjs, por otro lado veo muy bien su comentario pues orienta de alguna manera mejor a inclinarse sobre uno  u otro y cosas a tener en cuenta Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usar angular con require.js nunca me ha parecido una buena idea ya que angular tiene los módulos para encapsular y dividir la lógica de tu negocio y esto también es uno de los puntos más fuertes de require.js y la razón por la que más se usa. Esta es sólo mi opinion y en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529083/does-it-make-sense-to-use-require-js-with-angular-js) de SO verás que las opiniones son muy diversas.

Si el problema que enfrentas es un gran número de ficheros puedes usar automatizacion con [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) y [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) para inyectarlos en tu fichero index.html. Usando [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) puedes crear un proyecto que ya te haga eso por defecto con la ventaja de que puedes usar [gulp-angular-filesort](https://github.com/klei/gulp-angular-filesort) para inferir que módulo depende que quien automáticamente, tarea que debes hacer manualmente si usas require.js.

No obstante volviendo al problema en que te encuentras:

La razón por la que te está dando el error es porque los ficheros están cargandose en orden aleatorio ya que require.js por defecto va a tratar de inferir las dependencias y cargarlos todos lo más rápido posible. Al final de la [sección de carga de ficheros](http://www.requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles) se puede leer:

> Ideally the scripts you load will be modules that are defined by calling define(). However, you may need to use some traditional/legacy "browser globals" scripts that do not express their dependencies via define(). For those, you can use the shim config. To properly express their dependencies.
>
> If you do not express the dependencies, you will likely get loading errors since RequireJS loads scripts asynchronously and out of order for speed.

Que se traduce mas o menos en esto:

> Idealmente los scripts que cargarás son módulos que han sido definidos usando define(). No obstante, puede que necesites usar algún script tradicional que no exprese sus dependencias usando define(). Para esos casos puedes usar la configuración shim, para expresar sus dependencias apropiadamente.
>
> Si no expresas las dependencias, es muy probable que tengas errores de carga ya que RequireJS carga los scripts asíncronamente y sin orden para lograr mayor velocidad.

En la sección [mechanics](http://www.requirejs.org/docs/api.html#mechanics) se describe con un poco más de detalle el funcionamiento interno de require.js.

Esto no es problema cuando tu fichero está especificado usando el patrón de módulo `define(....);` en cualquiera de sus variantes pero desafortunadamente ni angular ni muchos otros plugins están escritos en ese formato por lo que debes especificar su configuración usando un `shim`

La solución es especificar el orden de carga usando las dependencias.

```
shim: {
   angular: { exports : 'angular' },
   ngRoute: { deps: ['angular'] },
   ngResource: { deps: ['angular'] },
   uiRouter: { deps: ['angular'] }
}
```

De esta forma le estas diciendo a los demás módulos que no son AMD que deben esperar por el angular para evaluarse.

**Update**

Se me olvidó mencionar que cada vez que tengas definas un módulo que exporte una variable global debes capturarla usando los argumentos de la función que especificas en el `define`. Lee [esta sección](http://www.requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulenotes) de los docs. Ej:

```
define(['angular', 'uiRouter'], function (angular){
    // Usa una variable local para acceder a angular
    // Require.js te dará el módulo correcto si lo has configurado bien
});
```

Debes usar una variable local que coincida con el orden de las dependencias que especificas; `ui-router` no exporta nada por lo que no es necesario referenciarlo.

Comment: Aun sigue saliendo el error, creo que es por el enrutamiento, sabes como se podria solucionar

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales Lee mi update que el problema puede estar por ahí.

Comment: Pues voy a ir pensando que el que esta cometiendo el error soy yo, debido a que, tengo el problema cuando trato de cargar el template, creo que estoy cometiendo el error de ir muy rapido, pero estoy cargando el template como lo ves alli, no se si esta bien, gracias de antemano

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales Me dices que tienes un problema al cargar el template pero eso no es el mismo problema que pones en la pregunta ya que require.js solo carga scripts y el template es un html. Puedes compartir una foto del problema que tienes, quizas usando [imgur](http://imgur.com/)

Comment: Pues la imagen esta arriba y el codigo esta alli, me refiero que no se si la forma en que estoy haciendo las rutas esta mal, o si también esta allí la estructura del folder, de igual forma, creo que estoy empezando a ver innecesaria el uso de las guias seas de john papa o de todd motto, no se si por que soy nuevo en angular, o simplemente nunca me ha gustado la idea de programar como lo hace alguien mas, seguire la forma por decir "normal". Ojala revises esto [enlace](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-setting-up-and-organizing-ionic-with-require-js/45107)

Comment: Por aqui dejo esto @devconcept, me sale ese error y no entiendo el por que no carga la pagina inicial, sinceramente que no lo se
[No carga el tema](http://imgur.com/pcpLYtP), y aqui sigue la
[Estructura del proyecto](http://imgur.com/UYwl2eS)